# React Native pod install fails

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios, react-native-cli

When I run **pod install** I get the following error:

> npx pod install
> error: missing required argument `module|git:/

react-native version: 0.63.4
node version: 14.10.1
npm version: 6.14.8

Please note I'm running the whole operation on Windows 10, not MacOS...

Incase someone can clear it out if I need to even run pod install on windows or is it not needed after auto-linking is introduced?

My **Package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "CollegeApplication",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "^4.13.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.9",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.11.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.5",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-camera": "git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.git",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^2.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.0.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.15.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**PodFIle**:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'CollegeApplication' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'

  pod 'react-native-camera', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-camera'

  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

  #reactNativePermissions for qrcode scanner https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera.podspec"

  pod 'react-native-netinfo', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo'

  target 'CollegeApplicationTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'CollegeApplication-tvOS' do
  # Pods for CollegeApplication-tvOS

  target 'CollegeApplication-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

Comment: I am getting exactly the same  - error: missing required argument `module|git:/' ` - after an `npx pod install`